# Waiting for function from sibling controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I have 2 controllers which are siblings. The first controller gets data from an $http request on click. The second controller has to retrieve this data, but I don't know how this controller will get the data because it has to wait for the function in the first controller before it can get its data.

This is the first controller:

```
$scope.getMessageData = function(username, full_url, main_item, item_id, sub_id){
    $scope.ajax_spinner = true;
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/getMessageData",
      params:{
        "adUsername" : username,
        "fullUrl" : full_url,
        "mainItem" : main_item,
        "tagId" : item_id,
        "subId" : sub_id
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.adUsername = response.data.adUsername;
      $scope.fullUrl = response.data.fullUrl;
      $scope.main_item = response.data.main_item;
      $scope.message = response.data.docs[0];
      $scope.sub_item = response.data.sub_docs[0];
      $scope.ajax_spinner = false;
      Data.setItem($scope.message)
    });
  };
```

The factory I use to share the data with the second controller:

```
App.factory('Data', function(){
    return { 
    setItem: function(item){
        this.item = item;
    },
    getItem: function(){
        return this.item;
    }
    };
});
```

The second controller:

```
App.controller("dataController", function($scope, $http, $sce, Data){
  $scope.message = Data.getItem();
  console.log($scope.message)
});
```

Now obviously $scope.message is undefined because the controller already loads on page load, but the getMessageData function is not ready called, so how can I "wait" for the second controller to load before getMessageData is fired?

Comment: Does the second controller also need to wait for the user to enter the query parameters and click a button on the first controller's HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$watch` in your `controller` to keep up with the changes in your `service`, e.g.

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch(function() {
  /* set Data.item value in your service */
  return Data.item;
}, function(item) {
  $scope.item = item || 'nothing here';
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', unwatch);
```

Or you could implement simple mechanism to register and unregister callbacks in your service to get notified when ever data is changed, e.g.

**Template**

```
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
  ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SomeController">
      SomeController
      <button ng-click="getData()">Fetch</button>
      <div ng-bind="data | json"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div ng-controller="OtherController">
      OtherController
      <div ng-bind="data | json"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('App', [])

.controller('SomeController', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.getData = function() {
    Data.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    });
  };
})

.controller('OtherController', function($scope, Data) {
  var callback = function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  };

  Data.register(callback);

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    Data.unregister(callback);
  }); 
})

.factory('Data', function($http) {
  var callbacks = [];

  return {
    register: function(callback) {
      var index = callbacks.indexOf(callback);
      if (index === -1) {
        callbacks.push(callback);
      }
    },
    unregister: function(callback) {
      var index = callbacks.indexOf(callback);
      if (index !== -1) {
        callbacks.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    getData: function() {
      /* where data.json is { "message": "My message" } */
      return $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        data.timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
        /* move inside $interval out of this fn maybe... */
        angular.forEach(callbacks, function(callback) {
          callback(data);
        });
        return data;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[image]